# Python numpy.compress() to reduce a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to reduce a NumPy matrix using the vector `u` and the `numpy.compress()` method, first going across the rows and then columns. Now my code looks like this:

```
n = 4 #number of rows/columns
square_matrix = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
u = np.array([1,0,1,0])

v = []

for i in range(n):
    v.append(np.compress(u,square_matrix[i]))

print(v)
```

I get the following output:

```
[array([1, 3]), array([5, 7]), array([ 9, 11]), array([13, 15])]
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I now create a matrix from the output again.
2. How could I repeat the same process for the columns. (My initial idea was to use a transpose of `u`, something like this:

```
for j in range((len(v_matrix[0])-1)):
    w.append(np.compress(u.transpose(),v_matrix[:][j]))
```

Comment: `u` is 1d, so transpose doesn't change anything.  Looks a bit like you read just part of the `np.compress` docs, ignoring or no understanding the `axis` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compress` like many `numpy` reduction functions takes an axis parameter:

```
In [166]: np.compress(u,square_matrix, axis=1)
Out[166]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 5,  7],
       [ 9, 11],
       [13, 15]])
In [167]: np.compress(u,square_matrix, axis=0)
Out[167]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Applying the compression sequentially:

```
In [168]: np.compress(u,np.compress(u,square_matrix, axis=0),axis=1)
Out[168]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

I didn't realize `np.compress` existed, though from the source file it must have been there from the start.  Boolean indexing is the same, and more common.

```
In [169]: bu = u.astype(bool)
In [170]: square_matrix[bu,:]
Out[170]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
In [171]: square_matrix[:,bu]
Out[171]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 5,  7],
       [ 9, 11],
       [13, 15]])
```

Boolean indexing is equivalent to indexing with the `nonzero` result:

```
In [177]: np.nonzero(u)
Out[177]: (array([0, 2]),)
In [178]: idx = np.nonzero(u)[0]
In [179]: square_matrix[idx,:]
Out[179]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

And that can be applied to both dimensions at once with:

```
In [180]: square_matrix[idx[:,None],idx]
Out[180]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

Without the reshaping (making the first a column), we get the diagonal:

```
In [181]: square_matrix[idx,idx]
Out[181]: array([ 1, 11])
```

and using the `ix_` utility:

```
In [185]: np.ix_(bu,bu)
Out[185]: 
(array([[0],
        [2]]),
 array([[0, 2]]))
In [186]: square_matrix[np.ix_(bu,bu)]
Out[186]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can I now create a matrix from the output again.

You can do the operation in a vectorized manner, just specify the `axis` keyword for `np.compress`

```
np.compress(u, square_matrix, axis=1)
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 5,  7],
       [ 9, 11],
       [13, 15]])
```

> 2. How could I repeat the same process for the columns. (My initial idea was to use a transpose of u)

Your suggestion is correct, but transpose the matrix instead of `u`. This will switch the columns with rows.

```
np.compress(u, square_matrix.T, axis=1)
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  9],
       [ 2, 10],
       [ 3, 11],
       [ 4, 12]])
```